# I want to add a category View for the Site using Virtuemart, which shows all Items in each category with the number of items inside each?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

i am using Virtumart Version is : 2.6.12.2
If you see this link: http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/
It shows Each category at the Top & the Products will be shown next line Horizontally.
i.e:

1) Top selling Items.
---List of the items ....horizontally & at the End a link " Show All"

2) Mobiles

-----Selected mobiles from mobiles category....at the end in the most right hand side.."View All"

### 3)Laptops ...

4) Bags 5) shoes...etc

It will continue like this for all the major categories.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).